# jQuery slideToggle breaking when you press a link inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have having a little trouble with the slideToggle when I have a link inside of the slideup panel. What I am trying to do is have the ability to press a button and a div will slide up and display related posts and once you press another or the related project button on the page it will close the toggle and reveal another effect that I am using (100% width and heigh popup). The script I am using works perfect but I am running into one problem. When I click a related post inside of the slideToggle it causes the div to slide down instead of going to the page that represents the link.

Here is my code below and an example http://jsfiddle.net/K8vBg/15/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// build a variable to target the #menu div
var menu = $('#menu')
// bind a click function to the menu-trigger
$('#menu-trigger').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    // if the menu is visible slide it up
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(1000);
    }
    // otherwise, slide the menu down
    else
    {
        menu.slideDown(400);
    }
});     

$(document).not('.projectHolder-small,#projectSpecs').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (menu.is(":visible"))
    {
        menu.slideUp(400);
    }
     });
     })
```

If I change .projectHolder-small,#projectSpecs in the .not function to just read #menu then I am able to click the link inside of the panel but the panel will not slideDown when I click another button on the page. The popup from #project specs will just go over the panel instead of closing it.

Is there something I am missing in my script?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the script to the following and it works perfect

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $frm = $('#menu').hide();

var $bts = $("#menu-trigger").on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this)
    $bts.filter(".selected").not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $this.toggleClass('selected');

    if ($this.hasClass('selected') && $frm.is(':visible')) {
        $frm.stop(true, true).slideUp(function () {
            $(this).slideDown()
        });
    } else {
        $frm.stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    }
});
$bts.filter('.selected').click();

$("#projectSpecs, #menuButton").click(function () {
    $bts.filter(".selected").removeClass('selected');
    $frm.slideUp();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `$(document).not().click()` to:

```
$(document).click(function(event){
    if(!$(event.target).closest('.projectHolder-small,#projectSpecs').length){
        if (menu.is(":visible")){
            menu.slideUp(400);
        }            
    }
});
```

I am using `closest()` instead of the usual `is()`, so that even clicking on the children elements of `'.projectHolder-small,#projectSpecs'` the panel won't close.

Comment: thank you for the post @marks I figured it out yesterday but wasn't able to post it until today.